# view does not seems to see $error variable in laravel middlegroup "auth"

Tags: laravel

I'm having problem on my view not seeing any `$Message` variable, which is working on my login controller.

```
public function index()
{
   $data = somedataFromModel::find(1);
   return View::make('SomeView',compact(['sampleData' => $data]);
}

public function postOrStoreData(CustomFormRequest $request)
{
   /* where update or insert or store occurs */

   //after all my updating codes or inserting codes
    return back()->with('Message','test');

}
```

with these codes I am not able to run my view correctly, it does not see `$Message`

[image]

it has the same implementation as my login controller and views.
right now my view needs to be authenticated to be used, so it is under the Middleware Group of 'auth', I also see the MiddleWareGroups, web and api. help me I'm lost.

My only objective is after I post any data, without using AJAX, just standard Form Action and Submit Method, I will display an alertClass with bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`redirect()->with()` stores it in the session.

[Per the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data), you thus access it via `session('Message')` in the view, not `$Message`.

The syntax may appear similar to `view()->with()`, but the functionality is not identical.

Comment: Is there a way to not use Session? will it affect other same function Views with different models containing the same session key and value?

Comment: It's a flashed session value, so it only exists once. If you navigate to another page afterwards, it won't be in the session any more, so it should have no impact on other pages.

Comment: ->with() is equal with Session::flash(), it mean you will only use it once, it won't affect anything

Comment: Or you can use Session::get('variableName');
You can check if parameter exists or not by Session::has('variable name'); in blade file

Comment: Okay guys, will try this :) Thank you very much

Comment: Update guys, I tried this, just plain Form Post, no Jquery no AJAX. it thus redirects but it does not have Session data. Am I right to use View::make? instead of plain view(); ? @ceejayoz

Comment: `View::make()` and `view()` are the same thing. Form POSTs have normal access to session data.

Comment: It's okay now, my bad, I have a package that uses FormRequest Primarily, I just double used it on the Controller part, that's why it calls it twice, because I wondered why my route does not go to the controller. Big Thanks my friend!